# http - change request url?

Tags: node.js, http

Is it possible to change the url of a HTTP-request without redirection?

For example instead of:

**request 1**

```
GET /user/abc123/ HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: /files/abc123
```

**request 2**

```
GET /files/abc123 HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
.
.
[filecontent]
```

I could could respond the file directly, but letting the client know that he got redirected:

**single request**

```
GET /user/abc123/ HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Location: /files/abc123
.
.
[filecontent]
```

Comment: Try to use UrlRewriter 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890043/apache-mod-rewrite-equivalent-for-node-js

Comment: @Bytyr Malik I'm asking on the low level of HTTP, and not for software solutions for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible to do this with HTTP. Redirection in HTTP specifically means the the client is supposed to send a second a request.

I think what you want is more akin to specifying a "canonical url" for some resources, and then having this canonical url displayed in the browsers location bar.

[RFC 6596](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6596) specifies a way to specify canonical urls with `<link rel="canonical">`. However, it does not specify what a browser should do with it, if anything. Google uses it to make better choices about which urls to index.

Other than using `<link>` tags, it's also possible to specify relationships between resources via the HTTP `Link` header, i.e. `Link: </better-url>; rel=canonical`. See http://www.w3.org/wiki/LinkHeader . I'm not sure if this would be picked up by Google though. The page at http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394 doesn't mention Google supports it. Browsers surely will disregard it, as they do with practically any link tag, stylesheets being the notable exception.

If the content in question is a HTML document, you could use the [HTML5 history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) for this. Specifically, use the `history.replaceState` method. I don't think achieving something similar is possible with other types of content.

#### Edit

`Content-Location` header may actually fit what you want quite well.
From section 14.14 of HTTP 1.1 RFC:

> The Content-Location entity-header field MAY be used to supply the resource location for the entity enclosed in the message when that entity is accessible from a location separate from the requested resource's URI. A server SHOULD provide a Content-Location for the variant corresponding to the response entity; especially in the case where a resource has multiple entities associated with it, and those entities actually have separate locations by which they might be individually accessed, the server SHOULD provide a Content-Location for the particular variant which is returned.

> ```
>   Content-Location = "Content-Location" ":"
> ```

```
                     ( absoluteURI | relativeURI )
```

> The value of Content-Location also defines the base URI for the entity.

> The Content-Location value is not a replacement for the original requested URI; it is only a statement of the location of the resource corresponding to this particular entity at the time of the request. Future requests MAY specify the Content-Location URI as the request- URI if the desire is to identify the source of that particular entity.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

See also [What is the purpose of the HTTP header field “Content-Location”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447679/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-http-header-field-content-location)

Comment: The Content-Location header really seems to be what I'm looking for, but sadly, I could not find a browser that supports it :(

Answer (score 1):

Well, it *is* possible, but it feels a bit dirty though.

A quick demo:

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();

app.get('/user/abc123', function(req, res, next) {
  req.path = req.url = '/files/abc123';
  next();
});

app.get('/files/abc123', function(req, res) {
  res.set('Location', req.url);
  res.send('files!');
});

app.listen(3012);
```

Comment: Yes, this implements what I mentioned above, but sadly, the browser does not display "/files/abc123" in the address bar after requesting "/user/abc123". It just ignores the Location header :(

Comment: Ah yes, I think I misunderstood what you want exactly. In that case, at least part of your solution has to be implemented client side, as Meryn already wrote.

Comment: The Location header has no meaning outside 30x, 201, 202 responses.

Comment: For me, changing just `req.url` was enough . I got errors if I tried setting `req.path` – `TypeError: Cannot set property path of #<IncomingMessage> which has only a getter`.

Answer (score 0):

This is my simple approach, not just change the originalUrl but the `path` too. My method suggestions:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("request", req.originalUrl);
    const removeOnRoutes = '/not-wanted-route-part';
    req.originalUrl = req.originalUrl.replace(removeOnRoutes,'');
    req.path = req.path.replace(removeOnRoutes,'');
    return next();
});
```

By this way `/not-wanted-route-part/users` will became `/users`