# $routeProvider not working and make request to the server with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I get **Cannot GET /login** when I pull *localhost:5000/login*  in the url . So the $routeProvider is not working and loading the view. Instead it is making the request to the server so basically it is fetching the page to the server. But I don't want to fetch the page to the server instead I want to load the view. My Application Structure is as follows:

```
lib

node_modules

public

----js

---------all js files like angular, script.js files here

----stylesheets

---------all css files here

views

app.js (main node file)

home.html

index,html

login.html

npm-debug.log
```

I have the following setup in the sever-side with app.js as:

```
var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app)
    //io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.use( app.router );


server.listen(5000);
console.log('listerning to port 5000');

app.use(function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('./index.html', {root: __dirname});
});
```

And on the client part the Angular script.js looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix = '!';

    $routeProvider.when('/login', {
        template: 'login.html', 
        controller: 'LoginController'
    });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: 'login'});
 }]);
```

My index.html file have a directive

I have no idea what I have done wrong. Any help could be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Angular's [HTML5 mode](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location#hashbang-and-html5-modes_html5-mode) requires additional server-side configuration.  When you enter `localhost:5000/login` in the browser, the request is sent to the server first and the server must be configured to return your `index.html` file and NOT the `login.html` file which is what your [express](http://expressjs.com/) application appears to be doing per the default behavior. I'm assuming that `index.html` rather than `login.html` is where the Angular application is bootstrapped and that must be loaded before Angular's route module can see that the route is `/login` and update your [`ngView`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.directive:ngView) directive based on your [`$routeProvider`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$routeProvider) configuration.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890043/apache-mod-rewrite-equivalent-for-node-js) looks like it might be useful in terms of URL rewriting with node.js.